# firewalld configuration will not allow http/https traffic

Tags: apache-httpd, firewalld

There is a hardware firewall in place, but I want to also product the system at the os level.

```
$ sudo firewall-cmd --list-all-zones
block
  target: %%REJECT%%
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces:
  sources:
  services:
  ports:
  protocols:
  forward: yes
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports:
  source-ports:
  icmp-blocks:
  rich rules:

dmz
  target: default
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces:
  sources:
  services: ssh
  ports:
  protocols:
  forward: yes
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports:
  source-ports:
  icmp-blocks:
  rich rules:

drop (active)
  target: DROP
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces: ens32 ens36
  sources:
  services:
  ports:
  protocols:
  forward: yes
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports:
  source-ports:
  icmp-blocks:
  rich rules:

external
  target: default
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces:
  sources:
  services: ssh
  ports:
  protocols:
  forward: yes
  masquerade: yes
  forward-ports:
  source-ports:
  icmp-blocks:
  rich rules:

home
  target: default
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces:
  sources:
  services: cockpit dhcpv6-client mdns samba-client ssh
  ports:
  protocols:
  forward: yes
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports:
  source-ports:
  icmp-blocks:
  rich rules:

internal (active)
  target: default
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces:
  sources: 10.10.0.0/24
  services: cockpit dhcpv6-client mdns samba-client ssh
  ports:
  protocols:
  forward: yes
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports:
  source-ports:
  icmp-blocks:
  rich rules:

nm-shared
  target: ACCEPT
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces:
  sources:
  services: dhcp dns ssh
  ports:
  protocols: icmp ipv6-icmp
  forward: no
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports:
  source-ports:
  icmp-blocks:
  rich rules:
        rule priority="32767" reject

public
  target: DROP
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces:
  sources:
  services: dhcpv6-client http https ssh
  ports:
  protocols:
  forward: yes
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports:
  source-ports:
  icmp-blocks:
  rich rules:

trusted
  target: DROP
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces:
  sources:
  services: ssh
  ports:
  protocols:
  forward: yes
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports:
  source-ports:
  icmp-blocks:
  rich rules:

work (active)
  target: default
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces:
  sources: 192.168.0.40 192.168.0.88
  services: cockpit dhcpv6-client http https ssh
  ports:
  protocols:
  forward: yes
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports:
  source-ports:
  icmp-blocks:
  rich rules:
```

When firewalld is active, the http/s is blocked.
When firewalld is stopped, traffic flows fine

Answer (score 0):

Needed to move the interface into public.

```
sudo firewall-cmd --zone=drop --remove-interface=ens32
sudo firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-interface=ens32
```